# String.Format not printing a value

Tags: c#, string.format

this code will not print the value year and I cant figure out why.

```
String words = string.Format("{0,-60}" + "|" + "{0,-7}" + "|" + "{0,-20}"  + 
"|" + "{0,-20}", Title, Year, Album, Artist);
```

Everything else works and if I print each value without formatting like this it works fine

```
String words = string.Format(Title + ", " + Year + ", " + album + ", " + 
Author); //works
```

Comment: What language is it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The way you have it you have only referenced the Title parameter in the format string.  Try `String words = string.Format("{0,-60}" + "|" + "{1,-7}" + "|" + "{2,-20}"  + 
"|" + "{3,-20}", Title, Year, Album, Artist);`

More information on the behavior of String.Format can be found here:  https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.format(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: You could also use string interpolation. i.e. `string words = $"{Title,-60}|{Year,-7}|{Album,-20}|{Artist,-20}";` which (at least for me) looks much more readable.

Comment: Agreed -- if you are using the C# 6 or newer string interpolation is the way to go.